# How to perform complex algebraic operation by group in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, algebra

I have data frame `mydata` that looks like this:

```
city district mean1 mean2 var

alpha A         1     2     0.5
beta  A         3     1     0.2
gamma B         1.5   1     1
zeta  B         2     0     3
...
omega C         1     1     2
```

I would like to perform some more complex arithmetic by group to be mroe specific I would like to calculate the following operation:

```
 sqrt(n(mydata))*((mean(mydata$mean1)-mean(mydata$mean2))/sqrt(mean(mydata$var))
```

I tried something like this with dplyr:

```
resutl<-mydata %>%
          group_by(district) %>%
          sqrt(n(mydata))*((mean(mydata$mean1)-mean(mydata$mean2))/sqrt(mean(mydata$var))
```

However, the above did not work because dplyr does not recognize it as a function. Of course, one solution would be to apply summarise function to calculate all means and observation count by group, put them in new data frame and then perform the calculation above by row, but is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr's mutate` function:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(district) %>%
  mutate(calculation = n() * (mean(mean1) - mean(mean2))/sqrt(mean(var)))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   district [3]
  city  district mean1 mean2   var calculation
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1 alpha A          1       2   0.5        1.69
2 beta  A          3       1   0.2        1.69
3 gamma B          1.5     1   1          1.77
4 zeta  B          2       0   3          1.77
5 omega C          1       1   2          0
```

Attention: I'm not sure, if you need the length of the whole dataset or just the subset. In the first case replace `n()` with `length(df)`.

### Data

```r
df <- readr::read_table2("city district mean1 mean2 var
alpha A         1     2     0.5
beta  A         3     1     0.2
gamma B         1.5   1     1
zeta  B         2     0     3
omega C         1     1     2")
```